# Wordpress plugin - users send files to owner

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm doing a WordPress page and I need that the people that visit the page can send to me (the owner) images.

I don't want them to be able to upload them to the page, I just want to be able to receive the images via mail.

Is there any wordpress plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

use contact form 7, create a form like this

```html
[text* your-name placeholder "Name"]

[tel* your-phone placeholder "Phone Number"]

[email* your-email placeholder "Email Address"]

Attach Image (upto 2mb)// normal hosting space is having this much upload limit only

[file* your-file filetypes:jpeg|png limit:2mb]

[textarea* your-message 40x3  placeholder "Message if any"]

[submit "Send Now"]
```

Go to Second Tab called as 'mail'-> Go Down and add this in file attachments - [your-file]

Save contact form and use the shortcode to display on your page as a form.

You will receive image in your email as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google forms:
https://www.google.com/forms/about/

Here is the example: 
https://www.iamm-kw.net/

scroll down to the button "Send Video"
when you click or tap the button, you will go to google forms website where you can log in with your google account and submit almost any heavy file.
You will be notified via email that somebody sent you a file.
The file may be logged in google sheets (kind of excel doc) with all the form values.
For example:
Name Joe Last Name Dow File Description this is my first attempt to take a good photo in the woods. Comments: please, accept this file
This Google sheets file will keep a log of all their uploads and whatever fields you specify in the upload form.
Cons: to upload a file they will need a Google account
Every time somebody visits the forms site, even without uploading anything, Google will send you a letter, that you have 15 GB left and if you don't want your users to have problems with upload, please upgrade your storage.
Pros: Fast and convenient. No plugins, no codes. big files, you can keep logs.